# Verify that the version of a file is correct before Compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, conditional-compilation

A file of Delphi's own LIBs has been changed, for a specific need. Since we have several programmers, I need to make sure everyone has this change, and in the future as well.

As the Delphi libs are installed and are not versioned, I need to verify that it is in the correct version.

I wanted to do this before compiling the version.

What I was able to do is create a hash of the file so I assure that it was not modified

```
{$IF  getMD5('C:\Delphi7\Lib\arquivo.dcu') = 'B1C1CBE80477S09AC4C1B39C28FE9619'}
    {$Message Fatal 'Version of file .dcu file in Delphi7 Lib is wrong..}
{$IFEND}
```

That way it does not work, because every moment returns the message of `[Fatal Error]`

Any idea?

Comment: You can't call a function in a conditional.

Comment: Any idea how to validate this then?

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite

Comment: Put the modified file into your project, or its search path, and then you don't need to modify the installation. Which you shouldn't do. My question to you is, how can you be sure that the source code for the project is the correct version? You use revision control. This modification is also part of your project, so shouldn't it be handled in the same way?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the file is in the delphi installation directory, there was a modification process, and a delphi installation was not done.

Comment: Yes, you said that already. When I do this I do not modify the Delphi installation, but I make sure that my modified file is linked to the executable. To me it seems much more robust to do that. It's simply impossible for it to go wrong for me because the modification is part of the revision control for the project.

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying files in the Delphi source or lib directory anyway. If you put your modified copy into your own source folder, and then check that file into your version control repo, the right version will be pulled every time a developer updates their source. If it's in your own project source folder, it will be used instead of the one in the Delphi\lib folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Delphi time was long ago, but my approach with C++ would be, to add a unique symbol to the lib, that the project depends on. Then, you will at least get a link time error if the symbol is missing (i.e. not your version of the lib is used).

How could this look like (not sure if this is feasible in Delphi)?
In addition to your modifications to the LIB, you also add a function called "MyModificationSentinelABCDEF()" that is empty (the name is not important, just make sure it is unique). Then, instead of the $IF statement you proposed, you add a call to this function and a descriptive comment to explains why it is there and what has to be done if there is an error related to it.

If the function is missing, you should see a compile/link error.

Comment: In Delphi, this would require making an `interface` change to the modified unit, which is not allowed when modifying units of the RTL/VCL/FMX and then including them into your project. You works have to recompile the entire RTL/VCL/FMX itself, which is not trivial

Comment: Hmm... - this is unfortunate :-)
I will modify my answer to highlight that this approach does not seem to be feasible. - Thanks for the hint

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm afraid that advice is not accurate. You cannot modify existing declarations in the interface section, but you can declare new constants, variables, types etc. I have reverted the answer because the original version is fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are you sure? My understanding is that *any* modification to the `interface` section increments the embedded version number in the DCU, and that leads to "Unit X was compiled with a different version of unit Y" errors in units that were compiled against the original unmodified unit

Comment: @Remy Yes, I am sure. I tested again this morning before I wrote the comment, and in fact I make use of this in my own projects.

Comment: It's been a while (Delphi 7-ish), but I used a similar check. I believe I just used a constant which I used in some dummy line in the dpr, but the effect was essentially the same. I don't believe I ever ran into that issues.